# Convert xhr to .wav

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, polymer-1.0

this is my code

```
fd.append('type', 'audio');
fd.append('file', audioBlob);
fd.append('name', 'example.wav');
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', url, true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

is there any way to convert this to a .wav file using Polymer 1.x?

Comment: Just FYI, it makes no sense to ask how to convert an `'XMLHttpRequest` to a wave file. It's a bit like saying "I have a baseball. I'd like to convert it to a car. How can I do that?" :). You appear to be sending data to a server, but beyond that, there's not much to go on. Please [edit] your question to include more details about what you have, and what you want. Please read [ask] for more information.

Comment: Save your data to a file and name the saved file with a .wav extension.